# Django generic UpdateView security issue

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

the code below allows the user to update his Company Profile and that works fine. The problem I am facing is that to get the user's CompanyProfile I have to pass a "pk" variable in the url, like this

```js
<a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" role="button" href="{% url 'user_profile_update' CompanyProfile.user_id %}"
               style="font-family: 'slabo'">Edit</a>
```

```js
url(r'^companyprofile_update_form/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UpdateCompanyProfile.as_view(), name='user_profile_update'),
```

this is the view

```js
class UpdateCompanyProfile(UpdateView):
    model = CompanyProfile
    form_class = CompanyProfileForm
    # fields = ['contactNumber', 'address', 'areaCode', 'deliveryEmails', 'keywords']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

As you can imagine, there is a number of users in the DB with their own CompanyProfiles. The problem is that a user can change the pk variable in the URL  and then have access to another user's CompanyProfile and then perform an update on that profile, and this is of course unauthorized access, how can I avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `get_object()` method for this:

```
from django.http import Http404

class UpdateCompanyProfile(UpdateView):
    model = CompanyProfile
    form_class = CompanyProfileForm
    # fields = ['contactNumber', 'address', 'areaCode', 'deliveryEmails', 'keywords']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        company = super(UpdateCompanyProfile, self).get_object(queryset)
        if company.user != self.request.user:
            raise Http404("Company does not exist")
        return company
```